# How do get unique matching records (see example)

Tags: sql-server

This example is just to illustrate the problem and is nothing like the actual data im working on but using anything that resembles the actual data would end up being horribly complex.

Assume I have these 2 sets:

```
id          name license
----------- ---- -----------
1           Joe  1
2           Eric 1
3           Jane 2
4           Mike 2

id          name     license
----------- -------- -----------
11          Van #1   1
12          Van #2   1
13          Truck #1 2
14          Truck #2 2
```

and I wanted to find 1 driver for each vehicle, that is qualified to drive it. (and for the sake of the example licenses are unique for each type of vehicle, no things like driving a truck qualifies the driver for driving vans). So the desired result would look like this:

```
driver_id   driver_name driver_license vehicle_id  vehicle_name vehicle_license
----------- ----------- -------------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
1           Joe         1              11          Van #1       1
2           Eric        1              12          Van #2       1
3           Jane        2              13          Truck #1     2
4           Mike        2              14          Truck #2     2
```

I have been able to get this result with the following query but it seems like it might get slow with bigger sets. Is there any other(better) way of obtaining the same results?

```
select d.id driver_id
       ,d.name driver_name
       ,d.license driver_license
       ,v.id vehicle_id
       ,v.name vehicle_name
       ,v.license vehicle_license
    from (select id
               ,name
               ,license
               ,rank() over (partition by license order by id) rank_driver
            from ( values ( 1, 'Joe', 1), 
                      ( 2, 'Eric', 1), 
                      ( 3, 'Jane', 2), 
                      ( 4, 'Mike', 2) ) driver (id, name, license)) d
   left join (select id
                  ,name
                  ,license
                  ,rank() over (partition by license order by id) rank_vehicle
            from ( values ( 11, 'Van #1', 1) , 
                      ( 12, 'Van #2', 1), 
                      ( 13, 'Truck #1', 2), 
                      ( 14, 'Truck #2', 2) ) vehicle (id, name, license)) v 
on d.license = v.license and d.rank_driver = v.rank_vehicle
```

Answer (score 0):

When you asking for the question that would be very very nice if you add DDL scripts for tables and script for sample data. If you have problems for performance, then you need to add proper indexes.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_drivers ON drivers (name) INCLUDE (license);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_vehicles ON vehicles (name) INCLUDE (license);

CREATE TABLE #drivers
(
    id INT, name VARCHAR(100), license int
);

CREATE TABLE #vehicles
(
    id INT, name VARCHAR(100), license int
);

INSERT INTO #drivers 
        ( id, name, license )
VALUES
(1,           'Joe',  1),
(2,           'Eric', 1),
(3,           'Jane', 2),
(4,           'Mike', 2);

INSERT INTO #vehicles
        ( id, name, license )
VALUES
(11,          'Van #1',   1),
(12,          'Van #2',   1),
(13,          'Truck #1', 2),
(14,          'Truck #2', 2)

SELECT a.id, a.name, a.license, b.id, b.name, b.license 
FROM 
(
SELECT id, name, license, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY license ORDER BY name) AS rownum
FROM #drivers
) a
JOIN
(
SELECT id, name, license, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY license ORDER BY name) AS rownum
FROM #vehicles
) b 
ON a.license = b.license
AND a.rownum = b.rownum
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: thanks for the DDL statements, i tend to use the "from (values" in these exercises. The solution you posted is however the exact same only changing rank to row_number.

Comment: First of all RANK is not the same as ROW_NUMBER. However I also added indexes.

Comment: I know that rank and row_number are not the same but for the purpose of this example they are interchangable, or are you trying to say that using row_number is somehow better in this situation?

Comment: yes, if you  would have the same driver name then you'll get into troubles. The same is with vehicle names.

Comment: only if the name columns would be included in the partition/order part of the function, which they are not.

Comment: yeah, sorry, my mistake. I was ordering by name, so my code wouldn't work with row_number :) Anyway try indexes they might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine.  I would write it as:

```
select d.id driver_id, d.name driver_name, d.license driver_license,
       v.id vehicle_id, v.name vehicle_name, v.license vehicle_license
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by license order by id) as rank_driver
      from drivers d
     ) d left join
     (select v.*,
             row_number() over (partition by license order by id) as rank_vehicle
      from vehicles v
     ) v 
     on d.license = v.license and d.rank_driver = v.rank_vehicle
```

If you are concerned about scalability, I would recommend indexes on the tables:  `drivers(license, id)` and `vehicles(license, id)`.

Although it is good practice to avoid using `*` in an outer query, it is overkill for subqueries -- unless you are generating a prepared statement or view whose compiled form is likely to last for a long time.  The database itself will optimize the query to select only the columns it needs.  (This is not true in MySQL which materializes subqueries, but that is another matter.)

Comment: thank you for your help and interest, i agree on the use of select * but i never do that in a SO question because of the dozens of people complaining about it instead of looking at the question ;)